# перенаправление http для tomcat+xwiki

Tags: tomcat

Как сменить http адрес с ip (http://10.0.2.101/xwiki) на http://xwiki?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы [доменное имя](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F) транслировалось в [IP-адрес](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81) на [вашей машине](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiVtdyA5d7YAhWLiiwKHS_YAekQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLocalhost&usg=AOvVaw0gAPOeGJ8R_cZGm0RSESrm) достаточно отредактировать файл [`hosts`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts).

---

Для локальной сети:

Если вы не администратор сети, вам нужно попросить администратора сделать на DNS-сервере запись, которая свяжет желаемое доменное имя для вашей локальной сети с IP-адресом, на котором приложение слушает порт. Обратите внимание, что необходимо, чтобы стандартный порт сервера, на который уходят запросы совпадал с портом, который слушается Tomcat-ом для вашего приложения на предмет HTTP-запросов. 
По стандарту это

```
<Connector port="8080" redirectPort="8443" connectionTimeout="20000" protocol="HTTP/1.1"/>
```

Если невозможно сменить порт, воспользуйтесь [port forwarding](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Если нужно поднимать DNS-сервер:

Поднимаем DNS-сервер [dnsmasq](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq). Он берет хосты из `/etc/hosts`:

```
  IP address    Host name
 192.168.1.1     host1
 192.168.1.2     host2
```

Теперь хост 192.168.1.1 ассоциирован с имене host1, а 192.168.1.2 с именем host2. Имеем поднятый DNS-сервер, но компьютеры в сети его еще не используют. Для использования DNS-сервера сам DNS-сервер нужно ассоциировать с некоторым IP-адресом. Для этого в `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` добавляем следующие записи:

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1
listen-address=192.168.1.64
```

Первая запись означает "использовать dnsmasq сервер" для самого dnsmasq сервера, а вторая запись - для всех остальных компьютеров в сети.

Для использования DNS-сервера клиентом необходимо отредактировать `/etc/resolvconf.conf` на клиентской машине, добавив запись

```
name_servers=192.168.1.64
```

На Windows можно воспользоваться, например, [OpenNIC](https://github.com/8bitgeek/OpenNIC-Wizard/).

---

Для [глобальной сети](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8) [Internet](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82) необходимо купить у [регистратора доменных имен](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%91%D0%BD) (далее *регистратор*) доменное имя  в определенной [доменной зоне](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F#%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0), купить [выделенный IP-адрес](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjm_bfI5d7YAhWnh6YKHf0uBTsQygQIMzAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FIP-%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B4%25D1%2580%25D0%25B5%25D1%2581%23%25D0%25A1%25D1%2582%25D0%25B0%25D1%2582%25D0%25B8%25D1%2587%25D0%25B5%25D1%2581%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B5_(%25D1%2581%25D1%2582%25D0%25B0%25D1%2582%25D0%25B8%25D1%2587%25D0%25BD%25D1%258B%25D0%25B5)_%25D0%25B8_%25D0%25B4%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B8%25D1%2587%25D0%25B5%25D1%2581%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B5_IP-%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B4%25D1%2580%25D0%25B5%25D1%2581%25D0%25B0&usg=AOvVaw1_MwBREEuXlKjyfXr1pTqg) и [ресурсы (дисковое пространство, CPU, RAM) на сервере](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi_6dzh5d7YAhXCFiwKHbv8AR8QFghUMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%25A5%25D0%25BE%25D1%2581%25D1%2582%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B3&usg=AOvVaw2FFnAstkfYYpX1W4XvosDb). 
Если регистратор и хостинг-провайдер - разные компании, то необходимо предварительно перенести доменное имя на DNS-серверы хостинг-провайдера. Выждать обновление [кэша](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88) DNS-серверов (до 24 часов). После перенести файлы проекта на дисковое пространство хостинг-провайдера и развернуть проект.